# Passing date as json object through Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Hibernate framework. And I have a problem in passing date as json object. Whenever I try to insert an object, it says error 400, request syntactically incorrect.

My controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/hospital", method= RequestMethod.POST,
consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public @ResponseBody Status addHospitalInfo(@RequestBody HospitalInformation hospitalInformation){   

try{
    if(hospitalService.addHospitalInfo(hospitalInformation)){

        return new Status(1,"Success");

    }else{
        return new Status(0,"Failed");
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return new Status(0,e.getMessage());
}   
}
```

My domain class is

```
private Integer hospitalId;
private String shortName;
private String name;
private Integer packageId;
private Date implementationDate;
private Date validFrom;
private Date validUpTo;
public enum SubscriptionType{Free,Complimentary,Paid}
private Integer totalUsers;
private Package packages;

public enum Status{Active,Inactive}

private SubscriptionType subscriptionType;
private Status status;
//normal getters and setters for other fields

@Column(name = "implementation_date",
            nullable = false)
    public Date getImplementationDate() {
        return implementationDate;
    }
    public void setImplementationDate(Date implementationDate)
    {
        this.implementationDate = implementationDate;
            }

    @Column(name = "valid_from",
            nullable = false)
    public Date getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }
    public void setValidFrom(Date validFrom) 
    {
        this.validFrom =validFrom;
    }


    @Column(name = "valid_upto",
            nullable = false)
    public Date getValidUpTo() {
        return validUpTo;
    }
    public void setValidUpTo(Date validUpTo) 
    {
        this.validUpTo =validUpTo;
    }
```

My Dao is

```
@Transactional
public boolean addHospitalInfo(HospitalInformation hospitalInformation)
        throws Exception {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    if(findByPackageId(hospitalInformation.getPackageId())== null){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        session.save(hospitalInformation);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return true;
    }

}

@Transactional
public Package findByPackageId(Integer packageId) throws Exception {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();

    List<Package> package1= new ArrayList<Package>();
    package1=session
            .createQuery("from Package where packageId=?")
            .setParameter(0, packageId)
            .list();
     if (package1.size() > 0) {
         return package1.get(0);
     } else {
         return null;
     }  
}
```

And my service class just saves the object into database. So I need help on how to pass date as json object. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue you can do one of the two things:

Either use a format that Jackson already recognizes `("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd")`

**or**

write a custom deserializer e.g. for `yyyyMMdd`

```
public class YourDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String date = jp.getText();

        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and annotate your date fields like

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDateDeserializer.class)
private Date implementationDate;
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDateDeserializer.class)
private Date validFrom;
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDateDeserializer.class)
private Date validUpTo;
```

**Serialization**

To have your dates printed the way you want in your JSON response, you can write a custom JSON serializer and annotate the fileds with it, so for `yyyyMMdd` something like

```
public class YourDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        jgen.writeString(format.format(value));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Date> handledType() {
        return Date.class;
    }
}
```

and than annotate your field, e.g.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDateDeserializer.class)
private Date implementationDate;
```

**Global config**

Note also that you can configure your custom serializers to take effect globally, by customizing Jackson's `ObjectMapper` that is in charge for the conversion. So something like

```
@Component
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("JsonDateModule", new Version(2, 0, 0, null, null, null));
        module.addSerializer(Date.class, new YourDateSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new YourDateDeserializer());
        registerModule(module);
  }
}
```

you would need to register your `CustomObjectMapper` with spring. If you're using the XML config, it would be something like

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="your.package.CustomObjectMapper"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Should he convert json to String first and then set the date. Is hibernate automaticaly make this conversion, how?

Comment: Spring MVC does it, and the problem he's facing `request syntactically incorrect` is not reaching hibernate still, it simply means that converter doesn't know how to convert the json's value of the matching property to `Date` field

Comment: could you please elaborate how and where do I mention the json format. And moreover I tried adding ur suggestion to my code. It still gives me the same error 400 whenever I hit the resource through postman.

Comment: good that you've asked, 'cause on a second look I noticed that I was wrong in my answer, hope it will be of more help now

Comment: It worked completely fine now. Except when I call the getDetail API , the date format I get is       "implementationDate": 1425234600000,
    "validFrom": 1425234600000,
    "validUpTo": 1425234600000.. So it would be a great help if you assist me with this as well. Thank you in advance

Comment: glad it helped, added the other way around, as well as some hints for configuring it globally